# Why does left shift float value work?

Tags: c++, floating-point, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

As I understand from
[Left shift Float type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315539/left-shift-float-type)
one cannot use left shift operator on float values. But when I tried it, it gave the same answer as multiplying by 2<sup>n</sup>.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    float a  = 1.1234;
    int b = (int)(a*(1<<10));
    int c = (int)(a*pow(2,10));
    cout << "\n a = " << a << " b = " << b << " c = " << c;
    return 0;
}
```

It outputs `a = 1.1234 b = 1150 c = 1150`
In which case will the two outputs (`b` and `c`) differ?

Comment: Do you know what `1<<10` is? No `float`s involved here.

Comment: @ᴍarounᴍaroun ah! I'm such an idiot.

Comment: No you're not, it happens ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int b = (int)(a*(1<<10));
```

Here, since both `1` and `10` are integers, you are performing left shift operation on integer instead of on floating-point number.

Answer (score 3):

you are multiplying 1024 with value of a(1.1234) in both case.
it does not mean you are shifting float value.