# typecast in Matlab

Tags: c++, matlab

I understood how typecast explained in the help file in the Matlab.
But can't cope for my result. I tried to typecast a 3x4 matrix as follow.

```
A= -0.0022  -87.8788  -96.2848  -96.9586
    0.9891  -52.9250  -52.7722  -52.7780
    0.1473   -4.8680   -6.0184   -5.9894

ANS = typecast(A(:), 'uint16');
```

Then ANS vector becomes

```
ANS=65304
    47886
    13518
    16253
    55853
    15894
    49650
    49839
    45875
    49747
    50835
    49307
    37329
    49856
     5820
    49747
    38546
    49344
    60110
    49857
     7340
    49747
    43369
    49343
```

That means -0.0022 have two 16 bits values of 65304 and 47886.
How is it calculated?
Then how can I implement in C++?
In C++, I implemented like

```
float f = -0.0022;
unsigned short a = static_cast<unsigned int>(f);
unsigned short b = static_cast<unsigned int>(f)>>16;
```

I can't have a and b as 65304 and 47886.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The value -0.0022 is being converted to two 16-bit values and that means your values are of type single (not double).

Let's try the other way around

```
>> typecast(uint16([65304 47886]), 'single')

ans =

   -0.0022
```

Now let's see the hexadecimal representation of these values look like:

```
>> format hex
>> uint16([65304 47886])

ans =

   ff18   bb0e

>> d=typecast(uint16([65304 47886]), 'single')

d =

   bb0eff18
```

Now you see that the first value, 65304, is the LSB 16-bit and 47886 is the 16-bit MSB. Therefore, your C++ implementation is correct. The reason that you do not get the correct values in C++ is that the value is not exactly equal to -0.0022. Since your environment is using the default [`format`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/format.html) of `short` you do not see all significant digits. if you try this

```
>> format long e
>> typecast(uint16([65304 47886]), 'single')

ans =

  -2.1819528e-003
```

or in your environment just using

```
>> format long e
>> A(1)
```

You find the actual value in the array, and using it in your C++ code, should return the correct value.

Comment: But something is still missing. If I tried in C++ like float f = -8.7878799e+001; unsigned short a = static_cast<unsigned int>(f);   unsigned short b = static_cast<unsigned int>(f)>>16;I got 65449 and 65535. Then I did typecast(uint16([65449 65535]), 'single'), I got NaN.

Comment: @batuman I think you need to use `reinterpret_cast` instead of `static_cast`. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers

Comment: Exactly. I did like float f = -8.7878799e+001;
    unsigned short a = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&f);
    unsigned short b = *reinterpret_cast<unsigned int *>(&f)>>16; The result is same as in Matlab.