# Which operators are defined for each of the base types?

Tags: c++, operators

Having used C# I was surprised to discover that C++ floats did not have the modulus operator defined. Nor are the bitwise operators apparently. I decided to learn more and went looking for a chart of which base types had operators defined for them and which did not but I couldn't find anything of that nature.

I know what all the operators are and how to overload them:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_operators

I do not, however, know which operators are defined for each of the base types.

Comment: Isn't it in the language specification? Maybe not all in one place, but if you look in the section on each type I expect it will say what operators are defined.

Comment: use fmod() for floating point modulus. And bitwise operators would be too specific to your floating point representation (apportionment between mantissa and exponent which many OSs allow you to change at run-time).

Comment: @Bathsheba Which OS lets you do that? I've never seen one. Floating-point is defined by IEEE 754 and hardware, not by the operating system.

Answer (score 1):

All operators are defined for integer types (`char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `long long` and `enum`). For floating point types (`float`, `double` and `long double`), you don't have `%` and none of the "bitwise" operators: `<<`, `>>`, `~`, `&`, `|` and `^`, since they don't make much sense for floating point. For example, what do you expect from `3.3 ^ 6.8`? [1] Or `1.9 % 13.4`? [1] There is no "remainder" in a floating point divide, so it's hard to envisage what it actually should give.

As mentioned in the comment, `fmod` does a similar thing to `%`.

[1] These are rhetorical questions, I don't expect anyone to come up with a good answer.

Comment: Re [1]: people did come up with an answer, hence `fmod`.

Comment: According to this question and it's link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers

Bitwise operations might be useful on floating point numbers in genetic algorithms. I would've assumed floats would support bitwise operations by default. Something like:

reinterpret_cast<unsigned int> float1 (bitwise operation) reinterpret_cast<unsigned int> float2

Comment: Yes, manipulating COMPONENTS of a floating point number with bitwise operations would be a valid thing - e.g. make a 32-bit float negative by : `float f; f = 8.3f; *reinterpret_cast<int *>(&f) |= 0x80000000;` - or one could manipulate the mantissa to round it down/up by changing the lowest bit or multiply by two by extracting and adding one to the exponent. But that's not using bit manipulation on floating point numbers - it's changing bits in a floating point number as if it is an integer (or a set of integer fields, really).