# With which variables operator >> is compatible

Tags: java, variables

I got little code here

```
int b=3;
b=b >> 1;
System.out.println(b);
```

It works perfectly, but when I change variable b to byte,short,float,double it contains errors, but with variables int and long it works perfectly, why it doesn't work with other variables?

Answer (score 7):

The bit shift operators, e.g., `>>`, are compatible with any integral types.  However, for smaller types like `byte` and `short`, the operation performs a widening conversion: the result is elevated to type `int`, and thus cannot be reassigned back to the source type.

Therefore, the following is **not** legal:

```
byte b = 3;
b = b >> 1;
```

But these assignments **are** legal:

```
byte b = 3;
b = (byte)(b >> 1)
int c = b >> 1;
```

As to why these operators don't work with `float` or `double`, I will leave that for you to explore.  Hint: consider the [layout of those types in memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) and what the implications would be for bit shifting operators.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator is defined for all integral types. It is not defined for `float` or `double`. With integral types, the result is always an `int` (or `long`, if the left operand is a `long`). Thus, when you use it with a `byte` or `short`, you need to cast back to the narrower integer type to do the assignment.

[Section 15.19 of the Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19) describes how the shift operators work. The first step is to apply *unary numeric promotion* to the operands; unary numeric promotion is described in [Section 5.6.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.1).

Answer (score 0):

Following on Mike's answer, this problem exists on other operators too. We cannot even compile this program

```
    byte b = 3;
    b = b + 1;  // error
```

I think the language designer got a little lazy when they reached here and took a shortcut.

Comment: However, one can do `b += 1`.

Comment: yeah, they probably got more coffee when they reached +=

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is that the operator must be defined for those types.
The bitshift operators >> and << aren't defined for them.

This post explains it pretty well:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723938/2225842

If I understand correctly, this is the same for both Java and C++.