# bit shifting, expression must have an integral

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to bit shift 63 places to the left. I keep getting an "expression must have an integral or unscoped enum type. I'm fairly new to C++ so I'm sure it's something very simple.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int sign_bit(double x){
    double temp = x << 63; // this is the line that is throwing the error
    int return_value = reinterpret_cast<int>(temp); 
    return return_value; 
}

int main(){
    double n = -1.00;
    double p = 1.00;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to the error, you can only bitshift integer types, try `static_cast<int>(x) << 63`

Comment: You cannot bit-shift a double, because floating-point values are stored in a form that is different from integral types. Try using a `long long` or an `int64`. Of course, that requires your platform to support 64-bit integers.

Comment: @AdamLiss The name of the type is `long long`, not `int64`, and it is required by both the C and the C++ standards (and I don't know of a modern compiler which doesn't support it, since it was required by C since C99).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't bit shift floating point types. And why exactly would you want to anyway? Try re-doing your code using integer types, or casting to int types, and see here: [How to perform a bitwise operation on floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers)