# logical operation on numpy array that was originally a pandas data frame

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

I have two variables that i want to perform on them elementwise logical operations. however I get the following error:

```
    tp = sum(actual & predicted)
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Below is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

train = 'train.tsv'
submission = 'submission1234.csv' 

trainSearchStream = pd.read_csv(train,sep='\t')

sample = pd.read_csv(path + 'sampleSubmission.csv')
preds = np.array(pd.read_csv(submission, header = None))
index = sample.ID.values - 1
sample['IsClick'] = preds[index]

actual = np.array(trainSearchStream['IsClick'].dropna())
predicted = np.array(sample['IsClick'])

tp = sum(actual & predicted)
```

Comment: Please post `actual.dtype` and `predicted.dtype`.

Comment: i get float64 for both @unutbu

Comment: Also, I get the following:  print(type(actual))
print(type(predicted))
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: I think that's the problem, I get same error message for `np.array([1.]) & np.array([0.])` but it's fine if I replace those with integers or booleans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, `actual` and `predicted` both have dtype `float64`. 
So the problem can be reproduced simply with

```
In [467]: actual = np.random.random(10)

In [468]: predicted = np.random.random(10)

In [469]: actual & predicted
TypeError: ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule
''safe''
```

`&` is [the `bitwise_and` operator](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bitwise_and.html). It makes sense for integers and boolean values; it [doesn't make sense](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1723575/190597) for floating point values.

You'll need to explain what you expected this to compute before we could suggest a fix.