# code error(invalid operands)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm having the following error:

> error-invalid-operands-of-types-int-and-float-to-binary-operator

Here is my code:

```
void DivComplex(float ,float, float ,float ) {

    const float divRe,divIm;

    cout << "Enter 2 complex numbers: " << endl;
    cin >> r1 >> i1 >> r2 >> i2;

    divRe = (r1*i1 + r2*i2)/(i1^2 + i2^2);
    divIm = (i1*r2 + r1*i2)/(i1^2 + i2^2);
    if(divIm < 0) {
        cout << "Devide is" << divRe << divIm << "j" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Devide is " << divRe << "+" << divIm << "j" << endl;
    }
}
};
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the *complete* and *unedited* error message, and also show us where in the code you have the errors.

Comment: `^ == xor` in C++. Use `std::pow` instead.

Comment: But a likely source of the problem is your use of the bitwise *exclusive or* operator `^`.

Comment: you should make habit of declaring and initializing constant variables at same time

Comment: That's the reason for the problem itsself: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers But you might want to look at `std::pow`.

Comment: For a power of 2, I would use plain multiplication `(i1*i1 + i2*i2)`.

Comment: thank you i use i1*i1 + i2*i2 and its ok !!! :)