# Getting absolute value from a binary int using bit arithmetics

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, mask, absolute-value

```
flt32 flt32_abs (flt32 x) {
    int mask=x>>31;

    printMask(mask,32);
    puts("Original");
    printMask(x,32);

    x=x^mask;

    puts("after XOR"); 
    printMask(x,32);

    x=x-mask;

    puts("after x-mask");
    printMask(x,32);
    return x;
}
```

Here's my code, calling the function on the value -32 is returning .125.  I'm confused because it's a pretty straight up formula for abs on bits, but I seem to be missing something.  Any ideas?

Comment: Is `flt32` some sort of nonstandard floating point format on which bit shifting is valid? See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/1723575/2564301

Comment: Jongware, by occasion, I've linked to that question in the answer below as well. Join you on the `flt32` type question.

Answer (score 2):

Is `flt32` a type for floating point or [fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic) numbers?

I suspect it's a type for fixed point arithmetic and you are not using it correctly. Let me explain it.

A fixed-point number uses, as the name says, a fixed position for the decimal digit; this means it uses a fixed number of bits for the decimal part. It is, in fact, a scaled integer.

I guess the `flt32` type you are using uses the most significant 24 bits for the whole part and the least significant 8 bits for the decimal part; the value as real number of the 32-bit representation is the value of the same 32 bit representation as integer, divided by 256 (i.e. 2<sup>8</sup>).

For example, the 32-bit number `0x00000020` is interpreted as integer as `32`. As fixed-point number using `8` bits for the decimal part, its value is `0.125` (`=32/256`).

The code you posted is correct but you are not using it correctly.

The number `-32` encoded as fixed-point number using `8` decimal digits is `0xFFFFE000` which is the integer representation of `-8192` (`=-32*256`). The algorithm correctly produces `8192` which is `0x00002000` (`=32*256`); this is also `32` when it is interpreted as fixed-point.

If you pass `-32` to the function without taking care to encode it as fixed-point, it correctly converts it to `32` and returns this value. But `32` (`0x00000020`) is `0.125` (`=1/8=32/256`) when it is interpreted as fixed-point (what I assume the function `printMask()` does).

**How can you test the code correctly?**

You probably have a function that creates fixed-point numbers from integers. Use it to get the correct representation of `-32` and pass that value to the `flt32_abs()` function.

In case you don't have such a function, it is easy to write it. Just multiply the integer with `256` (or even better, left-shift it 8 bits) and that's all:

```
function int_to_fx32(int x)
{
    return x << 8;
}
```

The fixed-point libraries usually use macros for such conversions because they produce faster code. Expressed as macro, it looks like this:

```
#define int_to_fx32(x) ((x) << 8)
```

Now you do the test:

```
fx32 negative = int_to_fx32(-32);
fx32 positive = fx32_abs(negative);
// This should print 32
printMask(positive, 32);

// This should print 8192
printf("%d", positive);
// This should print -8192
printf("%d", negative);

// This should print 0.125
printMask(32, 32);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int flt32_abs (int x) {
^^^            ^^^
    int mask=x>>31;
    x=x^mask;
    x=x-mask;
    return x;
}
```

I've been able to fix this and obtain the result of 32 by changing `float` to `int`, else the code wouldn't build with the error:

> error: invalid operands of types 'float' and 'int' to binary 'operator>>'

For an explanation of why binary operations on floats are not allowed in C++, see

[How to perform a bitwise operation on floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers)

I would like to ask more experienced developers, why did the code even build for OP? Relaxed compiler settings, I guess?

Comment: This code assume `int` is 32-bit 2's complement.  Common, but not defined by C.

Comment: Note: `int mask=x>>31;` --> implementation defined behavior. "An example of implementation-defined behavior is the propagation of the high-order bit when a signed integer is shifted right" C11 §3.4.1

Comment: Is the downvote by you? Shall I remove the answer? Until having read the answer above, I had had no idea about "fixed point", since it's sadly not taught at school.

Comment: when did you receive the DV?

Comment: Not sure about that, it was already there a few hours ago, when I first logged since yesterday.

Comment: And, I'm going to brush up on bit representation and arithmetics soon, now seeing my own deficiencies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102805/discussion-between-chux-and-iksemyonov).

Comment: Learnt to find the timestamp of votes, it was not by chux, but by someone else. My apologies.