# error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float') return (x & (1 << 31)) == 0

Tags: c++

Hi，I have a code like this:

```
STATIC bool is_pos_float(float x) {
  return (x & (1 << 31)) == 0;
}
```

But after compile, it shows:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')
  return (x & (1 << 31)) == 0;
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You need to get a bitwise copy of the floating point `x` as an integer. Floating point values makes no sense in bitwise operations. Also note that your code relies on implementation-specific details of the floating point format. Lastly, if you want to know if a floating point value is not negative, why not simply make that comparison? As in `x >= 0.0f`?

Comment: You can't use floats in a bitwise operation would be my first guess. Error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to perform a bitwise operation on floating point numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723575/how-to-perform-a-bitwise-operation-on-floating-point-numbers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left operand of built-in `operator&` must be an `integral` type, not `floating_point`.  Do this instead.

```
inline bool is_pos_float(float x) {
  return x > 0.0f;
}
```

Edit. Assuming that what the OP really wants is to muck around in the floating point format, I think this will work if the machine is Little Endian.

```
bool high_bit_zero(float x) {
    constexpr unsigned sz = sizeof(float);
    using raw = unsigned char[sz];
    raw *c = reinterpret_cast<raw*>(&x);
    return !((*c)[sz-1] & (1 << 7));
}
```

Comment: Fewest assumptions about representation here

Comment: Despite the function name, the question's code looks like it attempts to return true for `0.0f`. Your answer won't do that. May be worth mentioning in your answer.

Comment: @hvd - The `high_bit_zero` function I added returns `false` for -0.0f and `true` for +0.0f.

Answer (score -1):

What do you plan to do? Playing with the bits of a `float` variable???

If you are planning to make sure `x` is positive or zero, the solution is using `!(x<0.0f)`.

Converting `float` to `int` causes neglecting small numbers between `-1` and `+1` which does not work too.

If you insist on doing something hacky, have a look at [IEEE-754](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) standard:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

static bool is_posz_float(float x)
{
  static_assert(sizeof(float) == 4, "Unexpected type size!");
  union IEEE754{
    float number;
    unsigned char bytes[sizeof(float)];
  };
  IEEE754 a;
  a.number=x;
  return (a.bytes[sizeof(float)-1] & (1 << 7)) == 0;
}

void test(float x)
{
    if(is_posz_float(x))
        cout<<x<<" is a positive number or zero."<<endl;
    else
        cout<<x<<" is a negative number."<<endl;
}


int main() {
    test(0.1f);
    test(0.0f);
    test(3.14f);
    test(-0.11);
    return 0;
}
```

The results:

```
0.1 is a positive number or zero.
0 is a positive number or zero.
3.14 is a positive number or zero.
-0.11 is a negative number.
```

Comment: `int(x)` does something very different from the conversion you are implying.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, Thanks, have a look at my fix.

Comment: Assigning to one element of a union, and reading another is undefined behaviour.  You either need memcpy into a char array, or `const auto c = `reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&x);` and then use `c` as a pointer to the char array.

Comment: Why did you suggest `!(x<0.0f)` instead of just using `>=0`?

Comment: Your test cases need to consider #+INF, #-INF, and #NAN.  They are the tricky ones.

Comment: @MadPhysicist, because the original code does something similar. Anyway, I am relaying on the optimizer.

Comment: @MartinBonner. Is the undefined behavior just a C++ thing? I thought it was the whole point of unions in C.

Comment: what's the point of the assert and the hard coded size when you can use `sizeof`?

Comment: @MartinBonner, Where is it stated that union has an undefined behavior?

Comment: @MadPhysicist, It reminds you that this computer is not standard. IEEE754 might not apply.

Comment: I use [n4296](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) which is the pre-C++14 standard.  All other standards have similar wording.  Section 9.5 [class.union] says "In a union, at most one of the non-static data members can be active at any time, that is, the value of at
most one of the non-static data members can be stored in a union at any time."