# How to change/examine a value through bit manipulation without being undefined behavior in C++17 or lesser

Tags: c++, types, binary, undefined-behavior

There are some posts that are related more or less directly to this question but I'm missing a global and accurate answer.

For fundamental types, `value representation` (as defined in the standard) is more or less well defined. For instance, floating point have few constraints, except if `std::numeric_limits<T>::is_iec559` is true.
If I want to manipulate a `value representation` what operations are not UB, according to the type?
What guarantees, in the standard, the value is the expected one?

I personally nether encountered unexpected behavior, yet I have to consider now a larger set of architectures and OS thus I'm really interested in the deterministic behavior and portability of value manipulation through bits handling.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6971886/exotic-architectures-the-standards-committees-care-about), for instance, shows that there might be surprises if you don't take enough precautions.

Operations can be change of value or merely reading through bit hacks (getting/setting the sign (I know, nothing to really optimize there, it is just an example), getting an exponent or significand as integers,...).

I also made the assumption that the `<bit>` header is making things cleaner but perhaps I'm over-optimistic. Maybe it will be useful to complete any answer with a C++20 or greater version.

Advices appreciated to improve the question if needed.

Comment: "What guarantees, in the standard, the value is the expected one?" Nothing.

Comment: The proper way would be to `memcpy` back and forth between some buffer that allows bit modification and the actual value, nothing else I'm afraid.

Comment: what kind of buffer may allow for bit modification then?

Comment: @Oersted depends on the type, but for float it could be `std::byte buffer[sizeof float]` or `unsigned` in case `sizeof(float) == sizeof(unsigned)`, see: https://godbolt.org/z/cvhcnEbdY Note how memcpy is optimized: https://godbolt.org/z/bh7enqzTP

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI N4860 (for instance) 7.6.7 on shift operators implies that the value representation of integers follows the "natural" binary decomposition of integers, don't you think so? Thus, indirectly, individual bit access/modification, should have the expected outcome?

Comment: Integers may have padding bits.

Comment: For the reference, I would link [this post answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723938/21691539) and the intersting comments by @AnTstandswithRussia

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI, doing a bit (no pun) of maths on left shift operator definition, I think it implies that 1- padding bits or on the "left" (most significand side) if any, 2- the binary representation of unsigned integers is necessarily the "natural" one. You just have to be careful with radix and digits (in order not to manipulate the padding bits).

Comment: Yet I could make the following assumption: the padding bits can encode some compiler information dependent on the represented value. Thus twiddling with non-padding bits may make the all object inconsistent. I never heard of such implementation but it seems that the standard is leaving this possibility open. Am I wrong? (A yes may require some explanation)

Comment: Shifting and bit manipulation with `<< >> | & ~` is Ok. Copying to a char array, fiddling with its bits, and copying back may or may not be, depending on whether you have trap representations/padding bits.

Comment: pushing farther, if ```T``` is a fundamental integral type and ```sizeof(T)*std::numeric_limits<unsigned_char>::digits == std::numeric_limits<T>::digits```, can we conclude that there is no padding bits and thus that we can do bit twiddling? The situation, on the other hand, seems hopeless for floating point types.